# Sum of predictors in a Linear Regression of Indicator Matrix

Tags: regression

Probably a very basic question, but could someone please provide a proof of how the sum of predictors for the indicator matrix linear regression always becomes 1 when the model has an intercept? Seems intuitive, but having problems to derive this mathematically.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I will flag this question as a duplicate, I have answered it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/384931/189506)